# Is it possible to release PHP web application as an desktop application?

Tags: php, virtual-machine, virtualization

I've made a PHP application and some customers want to install it on their own desktops. But I don't want to install nginx, PHP, MySQL, Redis, etc separately for each customer and then install my web application separately. It's too hard and prone to a lot of problems.

I'm looking for something like a virtual machine that everything is already installed and set up on it, then I just deliver that to the customer. When customer starts this machine, the machine listens to a port on their desktop and the customer can access my web application through a web browser on localhost (or a browser inside that machine?).

Is this possible? How?

Comment: To run PHP on a PC, that PC needs PHP to be installed

Comment: @MehdiBounya. Yes, but we can install php on a virtual machine and deliver machine's file (e.g. `.vbox` file of Oracle's VirtualBox). I'm looking for something specially designed for this purpose.

Comment: Well you still need to Install virtual box on all those machines, if you can do so, why don't you just use XAMPP or WAMP?

Comment: Installing and configuring XAMPP for each client is too hard and time taking, because for example, the client may have mysql installed on their desktop and there is conflicting issues.
But with something like a Virtual Machine, everything runs in a virtual computer, not in their own desktop. If we configure that virtual machine once, we can run it on any computer in the world without any problem.
But using normal VMs like VirtualBox is too hard too, because they are designed for general purpose.

Comment: This is a job for Docker.